# Video Tag plays two videos at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added two video tags with bootstrap e.g below, so that I can fire video with controls on mobile.

But it plays dual video on browser on mobile its perfect. Adding display none dosen't work with media queries

```
<video id="mobileVideo" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm videoOne" poster="http://crudism.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IMG_3570.jpg" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" loop>
    <source class="hidden-md hidden-lg" src="iphone.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source class="hidden-md hidden-lg" src="iphone.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source class="hidden-md hidden-lg" src="iphone.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

For Mobile use:

```
<video id="mobileVideo" class="hidden-md hidden-lg videoOne" poster="http://crudism.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IMG_3570.jpg" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" loop>
    <source class="hidden-md hidden-lg" src="iphone.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source class="hidden-md hidden-lg" src="iphone.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source class="hidden-md hidden-lg" src="iphone.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: Please provide your complete code and not only the video tags.

Comment: You are still missing the part, where you switch the videos for mobile/desktop devices. That are still only to video tags. I can't see what you're doing with them.

Comment: Don't use the same id on the two video tags, an id should always be unique. Might or might not solve this problem, but it will prevent a lot of other problems in the future.

Comment: autoplay tag makes them play both in desktop but in mobile it is not supported